# Linear gradient behavior changes upon element cloning

Tags: javascript, html, css, linear-gradients

The code below has a rating scale and a scale field. The desired behavior is to keep the linear gradient behavior the same as before changing `scale` value. Whenever `scale` value is changed, the linear gradient is gone or freezes which is shown below.

```js
function getIdPrefix(assignedPrefix) {
    const matches = assignedPrefix.match(/^(.+)-[0-9]+$/);
    if (matches !== null) {
        return matches[1];
    }
}


function scaleModified(scaleField, min = 2, max = 15) {
    const scale = Math.min(Math.max(scaleField.value, min), max);
    const ratingContainer = scaleField
        .closest('.input-group')
        .querySelector('.box > .rating');
    const radioBtn = ratingContainer
        .querySelector('input[type="radio"]')
        .cloneNode(true);
    const label = ratingContainer.querySelector('label').cloneNode(true);
    const idPrefix = getIdPrefix(radioBtn.id);
    ratingContainer.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = scale; i > 0; --i) {
        const radioClone = radioBtn.cloneNode(true);
        radioClone.id = `${idPrefix}-${i}`;
        ratingContainer.append(radioClone);
        const labelClone = label.cloneNode(true);
        labelClone.textContent = i.toString();
        labelClone.for = radioClone.id;
        ratingContainer.append(labelClone);
    }
}
```

```css
 

.small-numeric-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center
}

.small-numeric-container label {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.numeric-small {
    width: 85px;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.rating {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #20c997, #0f5132);
}

.rating input {
    display: none;
}

.rating label {
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background: #212529;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.h-separator {
    width: 10px;
}

.rating input[type="radio"]:hover ~ label, .rating input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
    background: transparent;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
 
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
<div class="small-numeric-container">
    <input class="form-control user-input numeric-small replicable" id="id_0-scale" max="15" min="2"
           oninput="scaleModified(this)" placeholder="Scale" type="number" value="10">
</div>
<span class="h-separator"></span>
<div class="box">
    <div class="rating">
        <input id="rating-label-10" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-10">10</label>
        <input id="rating-label-9" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-9">9</label>
        <input id="rating-label-8" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-8">8</label>
        <input id="rating-label-7" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-7">7</label>
        <input id="rating-label-6" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-6">6</label>
        <input id="rating-label-5" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-5">5</label>
        <input id="rating-label-4" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-4">4</label>
        <input id="rating-label-3" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-3">3</label>
        <input id="rating-label-2" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-2">2</label>
        <input id="rating-label-1" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-1">1</label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to set the `htmlFor` property of the label element which represents the for html attribute.

```js
function getIdPrefix(assignedPrefix) {
    const matches = assignedPrefix.match(/^(.+)-[0-9]+$/);
    if (matches !== null) {
        return matches[1];
    }
}


function scaleModified(scaleField, min = 2, max = 15) {
    const scale = Math.min(Math.max(scaleField.value, min), max);
    const ratingContainer = scaleField
        .closest('.input-group')
        .querySelector('.box > .rating');
    const radioBtn = ratingContainer
        .querySelector('input[type="radio"]')
        .cloneNode(true);
    const label = ratingContainer.querySelector('label').cloneNode(true);
    const idPrefix = getIdPrefix(radioBtn.id);
    ratingContainer.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = scale; i > 0; --i) {
        const radioClone = radioBtn.cloneNode(true);
        radioClone.id = `${idPrefix}-${i}`;
        ratingContainer.append(radioClone);
        let labelClone = label.cloneNode(true);
        labelClone.textContent = i.toString();
        labelClone.htmlFor = radioClone.id;
        ratingContainer.append(labelClone);
    }
}
```

```css
.small-numeric-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center
}

.small-numeric-container label {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.numeric-small {
    width: 85px;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.rating {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #20c997, #0f5132);
}

.rating input {
    display: none;
}

.rating label {
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background: #212529;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.h-separator {
    width: 10px;
}

.rating input[type="radio"]:hover ~ label, .rating input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
    background: transparent;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
<div class="small-numeric-container">
    <input class="form-control user-input numeric-small replicable" id="id_0-scale" max="15" min="2"
           oninput="scaleModified(this)" placeholder="Scale" type="number" value="10">
</div>
<span class="h-separator"></span>
<div class="box">
    <div class="rating">
        <input id="rating-label-10" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-10">10</label>
        <input id="rating-label-9" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-9">9</label>
        <input id="rating-label-8" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-8">8</label>
        <input id="rating-label-7" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-7">7</label>
        <input id="rating-label-6" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-6">6</label>
        <input id="rating-label-5" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-5">5</label>
        <input id="rating-label-4" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-4">4</label>
        <input id="rating-label-3" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-3">3</label>
        <input id="rating-label-2" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-2">2</label>
        <input id="rating-label-1" name="rating" type="radio">
        <label for="rating-label-1">1</label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```